# How to pass in a method as a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I've just noticed I'm repeating a lot of C# code in my ASP.NET application so want to create a generic method. I have a series of private methods like this:

```
private void PopulateMyRepeatedControl()
{
    DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
    DataTable symbols = GetSelectedSymbols();
    DataTable tradeGrades = GetSelectedTradeGrades();
    DataTable executionGrades = GetSelectedExecutionGrades();        

    chtMyRepeatedChart.DataSource = DB.MyRepeatedCall (
        int.Parse(txtStartBalance.Text),
        int.Parse(ddlTradeTypes.SelectedValue),
        ddlRepeatedTrades.SelectedValue,
        radSide.SelectedValue,
        ddlTradeSetups.SelectedValue,
        symbols,
        ddlChartTimeFrames.SelectedValue,
        int.Parse(ddlHours.SelectedValue),
        int.Parse(ddlYears.SelectedValue),
        int.Parse(ddlMonths.SelectedValue),
        int.Parse(ddlDays.SelectedValue),
        int.Parse(ddlNumSCs.SelectedValue),
        txtDateFrom.Text,
        txtDateTo.Text,
        tradeGrades,
        executionGrades,
        int.Parse(txtMinProfitPips.Text),
        int.Parse(txtMaxProfitPips.Text));

    chtMyRepeatedChart.DataBind();
}
```

So, I want to replace `DB.MyRepeatedCall`, `chtMyRepeatedChart` and pass them in as parameters to a generic function. Is that possible? I have many charts on my form that take the same number of parameters.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
Following Frederik's solution I have done this:

```
private delegate IEnumerable<DataTable> GetDataSource(
    int TradeType,
    string RepeatedTrades,
    string Side,
    string TradeSetup,
    DataTable symbols,
    string ChartTimeFrame,
    int Hour,
    int Year,
    int Month,
    int Day,
    int NumSCs,
    string DateFrom,
    string DateTo,
    DataTable TradeGrades,
    DataTable ExecutionGrades,
    int MinProfitPips,
    int MaxProfitPips);

private void PopulateControl(Chart chart, GetDataSource getDataSource)
{
    //DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
    DataTable symbols = GetSelectedItems("symbol", listSymbols);
    DataTable tradeGrades = GetSelectedItems("tradeGrade", listTradeGrades);
    DataTable executionGrades = GetSelectedItems("executionGrade", listExecutionGrades);

    chart.DataSource = getDataSource(
        int.Parse(ddlTradeTypes.SelectedValue),
        ddlRepeatedTrades.SelectedValue,
        radSide.SelectedValue,
        ddlTradeSetups.SelectedValue,
        symbols,
        ddlChartTimeFrames.SelectedValue,
        int.Parse(ddlHours.SelectedValue),
        int.Parse(ddlYears.SelectedValue),
        int.Parse(ddlMonths.SelectedValue),
        int.Parse(ddlDays.SelectedValue),
        int.Parse(ddlNumSCs.SelectedValue),
        txtDateFrom.Text,
        txtDateTo.Text,
        tradeGrades,
        executionGrades,
        int.Parse(txtMinProfitPips.Text),
        int.Parse(txtMaxProfitPips.Text));

    chart.DataBind();        
}
```

I am calling the function with this command:

```
PopulateControl (chtEquityCurve, DB.GetAccountBalances());
```

I get this error in the intellisense:
`No overload for method 'GetAccountBalances' takes 0 arguments.`

Comment: Consider using expression trees even though it's not an easy solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make a delegate type (typically I recomment people to use one of the available `Func` delegates, but they support only up to 16 input paramters, you have 18). Give it an appropriate name and define all the input parameters so they have the correct type and descriptive names. Make the delegate return an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public delegate IEnumerable<WhateverTypeIsReturned> GetDataSource(int firstParam, [...]);
```

Then, modify `PopulateMyRepeatedControl` so that it looks like this:

```
private void PopulateMyRepeatedControl(Chart chart, GetDataSource getDataSource)
{
    DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
    DataTable symbols = GetSelectedSymbols();
    DataTable tradeGrades = GetSelectedTradeGrades();
    DataTable executionGrades = GetSelectedExecutionGrades();        

    chart.DataSource = getDataSource (
        int.Parse(txtStartBalance.Text),
        int.Parse(ddlTradeTypes.SelectedValue),
        ddlRepeatedTrades.SelectedValue,
        radSide.SelectedValue,
        ddlTradeSetups.SelectedValue,
        symbols,
        ddlChartTimeFrames.SelectedValue,
        int.Parse(ddlHours.SelectedValue),
        int.Parse(ddlYears.SelectedValue),
        int.Parse(ddlMonths.SelectedValue),
        int.Parse(ddlDays.SelectedValue),
        int.Parse(ddlNumSCs.SelectedValue),
        txtDateFrom.Text,
        txtDateTo.Text,
        tradeGrades,
        executionGrades,
        int.Parse(txtMinProfitPips.Text),
        int.Parse(txtMaxProfitPips.Text));

    chart.DataBind();
}
```

When you call the method, simply pass the chart and the method to use for collecting data:

```
PopulateMyRepeatedControl(oneChart, OneDataCollectionMethod);
PopulateMyRepeatedControl(anotherChart, AnotherDataCollectionMethod);
```

Of course, `TheDataCollectionMethod` must have the correct signature, otherwise the code will not compile.

**Update**
Regarding your update; note that you want to pass the method as an argument, not invoke it:

```
PopulateControl (chtEquityCurve, DB.GetAccountBalances);
```

Note that there are no paranthesis after the method name.

Comment: Why if i use Func delegate with List<List<T> as a single parameter

Comment: @Saurabh: That would certainly work but it would be less type-safe. Another option would be to create a type with properties for holding the various input values (let's call it `ChartDataSettings`), and use `Func<ChartDataSettings>`.

Comment: Thanks I also have a `DetailsView` object on the same form that I want to populate in the same way. What would I use instead of `Chart` in `PopulateMyRepeatedControl`?

Comment: @Fredirik: Please can you check the UPDATE section of my question?

Comment: @Fredrik: Thanks, I've removed the parantheses, but I get this error now: `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'ASP.summarystats_aspx.GetDataSource`

Comment: @Mark: make sure that `GetAccountBalances` have the same signature (meaning the same number of parameters of the same types, and the same return type) as the `GetDataSource` delegate.

Comment: OK, thanks. I have 2 more issues: `GetAccountBalances` take one extra parameter than all the other methods on the form, with the other parameters in `GetAccountBalances` being exactly the same. I also want to use the same code to populate a `DetailsView` control as well as all the `Chart` controls. Thanks for your help so far, I'm nearly there...

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. I am getting this error when calling PopulateControl: `'System.Data.DataTable DatabaseComponent.DBUtil.GetSummaryStats(int, string, string, string, System.Data.DataTable, string, int, int, int, int, int, string, string, System.Data.DataTable, System.Data.DataTable, int, int)' has the wrong return type`

Comment: @Mark: Yes, the method `GetSummaryStats` must match the delegate signature *exactly*. The delegate specifies that the method should return `IEnumerable<DataTable>`, but `GetSummaryStats` returns `DataTable`.

Comment: @Fredirik: Ah ok great. I've managed to populate my `DetailsView` control using a delegate and changing the `Chart` object in `PopulateControl` to a `CompositeDataBoundControl`. However when I try and populate a `Chart`, it doesn't work with this error: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl'` Is there a way to populate both `Chart` controls and `DetailsView` controls using the same `PopulateControl` function? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @Mark: now we are moving a bit off my regular territory, but I'd try to use `DataBoundControl` instead of `CompositeDataBoundControl`: both `Chart` and `CompositeDataBoundControl` inherit from `DataBoundControl`, so that could probably work.

Comment: @Fredrik: great, that worked! All working fine now. One more Q, if I may!? One of my charts takes one extra parameter. How would you handle that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider using some OOPs concepts rather going to parametrize the method name. As you have method which takes parameters which are actually the controls, think of separating this to different classes.

First you should think of re-factoring the code, because single method has too many parameters. You can encapsulate all the parameters to a class like

```
public class RepeatedCallParameters
{
   public string StartBalance{get;set;}

   ...

   ...
}
```

Then you can have a abstract class with all these parameters and a method PrepareRepeatedCallParameters()

```
public abstract class ChartProperties : Page
{
    protected abstract int StartBalance {get;}

    public RepeatedCallParameters PrepareRepeatedCallParameters()
    {
         RepeatedCallParameters p = new RepeatedCallParamters();
         p.StartBalance = StartBalance;
         return p;  
    }
}
```

Then

You can implement this class in the page

```
public class YourPage: ChartProperties
{
   protected override int StartBalance
   {
     get {return int.Parse(txtStartBalance.Text);} 
   }

   //All properties
   ..

   private void BindChartData()
   {
      RepeatedCallParameter p  = PrepareRepeatedCallParameters();
      Chart.DataSource = DB.RepeatedCall(p);
      Chart.DataBind();   
   }
}
```

This way you can have the code of populating the parameters in the single place i.e in the abstract class.

Comment: I like this solution, thanks. My Page already inherits from a class called PageWithStatus. So should ChartProperties inherit from PageWithStatus which inherits from Page, or should it be PageWithStatus inherits from ChartProperties which inherits from Page? Getting a little confused here.

Comment: You can go like this Page inherits PageWithStatus and then PageWithStatus inheriting ChartProperties.

Comment: @Mark Allsion: Do you require both the Status and ChartProperties in all the pages? If you require both then you can join both these classes.

Comment: @dhinesh: I require the Status in all pages but the ChartProperties in only one page at the moment - however I may require the ChartProperties in another page later, not sure yet.

Comment: @Mark Allision:Can you keep an property of PageStatus in the ChartProperties and inherit with the ChartProperties in the single page and all other page you can use the PageStatus as usual.

Comment: @dhinesh: Do I need to mark the properties as abstract? i.e. `protected abstract int TradeType {get; }` because I get this message: `PageWithProperties.TradeType.get must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors.` I've renamed my class to PageWithProperties and included the properties from my old PageWithStatus class.

Comment: Yes all the properties needs to be abstract in the abstract class, only the method needs to be implemented. I will edit the answer as well.

Comment: @Mark: Whether PageWithStatus was abstract class or Concrete class?

Comment: @dhinesh: Thanks, PageWithStatus was a concrete class.

Comment: @dhinesh: On my chart page it doesn't like the return statement in the protected properties. i.e. this line: `return int.Parse(txtStartBalance.Text);`. I get this error: `A get or set accessor expected`. Do you know why this is? Thanks.

Comment: protected int StartBalance
   {
     get {return int.Parse(txtStartBalance.Text); }
   } encapsulate that in get. it should work.

Comment: @Mark: Also use the override. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

something like below

```
PopulateMyRepeatedControl(Chart c , Func<List<List<T>>>  actionToBeCalled)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using delegates, which can be thought of as a type-safe function pointer.  Delegates are made up of a delegate type and delegate instance.  I would recommend using the built in generic delegate types Action and Func.  Action has no return type, Func does.

```
public void MyMethod(Func<int, bool> predicate)
{
  if (predicate(5))
  {
    // true
  }
  else
  {
    // false
  }
}

// To call MyMethod, pass a delegate instance (here we are using a lambda expression)
MyMethod(x => x > 5);
```

The delegate instance gets called from MyMethod (as the predicate parameter), and because of the logic used, if the value is 5, false will be returned, otherwise any value greater than 5, true will be returned.  You can see how the logic of the predicate is decoupled from the MyMethod method, which makes MyMethod reuseable for any piece of logic.

Note the last generic type used in Func is the return type, Action has no return types.  Both delegate types take up to 16 parameters, but you probably want to think about your design if you need this many!

Comment: Just a little detail: You could shorten this call to `MyMethod(x => x > 5);`, which is equivalent.